# Can't have my <div> element without a newline before it

Tags: html, css

I want to make an animation, and it works, however the word Alan Turing is starting from a new line, but I don't want it. Span tag and display:inline or diplay:inline-block are not working.
Here is a fragment of my CSS:

```css
.inf{
    position: relative;
}


.inf ul{
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  left: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}



.inf li ,
.products li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition:0.5s;
}



.inf a ,
.products a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.inf button:hover + ul{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

Here is my HTML.

```html
<div style="display: inline-block" class='inf'>
  <button class="author">Alan Turing</button>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>bla bla bla</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a working example, if you want you can modify the snippet i insert in your question

Answer (score 0):

Rename "inline-block" to "block".

Example:

```html
<div style="display: block" class='inf'>
  <button class="author">Alan Turing</button>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>bla bla bla</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```